# MySQL Partitioning Performance

Tags: mysql, myisam, partitioning

I have a MyISAM table with billions of rows that is still causing me problems because the indexes, even after I shortened them as much as possible, do not fit in my 64GB of RAM.

I am unable to index the table and this is causing serious problems.

I thought that partitioning might be the answer to the problem, but I'm not sure because I `SELECT` on all kinds of different column combinations.

The table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE research_storage1b (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `word1` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `word2` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `origyear` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cat` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `pibn` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `page` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `pos` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `num` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `pibnpage` (`pibn`,`page`),
  KEY `word21pibn` (`word2`,`word1`,`pibn`),
  KEY `word12num` (`word1`,`word2`,`num`),
  KEY `year1` (`origyear`,`word1`),
  KEY `catyear` (`cat`,`origyear`),
  KEY `pibn` (`pibn`,`word1`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=ascii COLLATE=ascii_bin
DATA DIRECTORY='/storage/researchdb' 
INDEX DIRECTORY='/storage/researchdb';
```

The indexes are representative of the different `SELECT` statements, i.e. sometimes I'm retrieving `pibn` based on the `word1`, and sometimes I'm retrieving `word1` based on `pibn`.

If I had to choose something to split the table on, it would probably be `word1` because this is most searched for. But there are some queries that will be selecting `word1`, or counting `word1`, in which case would I be correct in assuming the partitioning would drastically slow those queries down? There are around 500,000 unique values for `word1`.

My main questions are:

1. Should I use partitioning (will it solve my indexing issue)?
2. Should I partition on `word1`?
3. How many partitions should I have? (I'm thinking maybe 100?)
4. How do I modify the `CREATE TABLE` to have 100 (or however many) partitions split on `word1` (or another column)?
5. Since `word1` is not a primary key... do I have to change the primary key to an index, or something like that? (I didn't fully understand this part of the partitioning docs/tutorials.)

Please help if you can, thank you.

Comment: What is the proportion of writes into this table? Do writes matter a lot?